# How to use a simple Spring Security AuthenticationProvider without logon page?

Tags: java, spring-security

I have a simple authentication provider that I'm trying to use with Spring Security.

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:http>
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        ref="ipAddressAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Currently, with the above configuration, the user is redirected to a logon page when the first visit. I do not want this redirect. I'm trying to hit this authentication provider on every page visit. Any way to make this work without writing additional custom code?

I'm guessing I need to cleanly get rid of form filter and basic filter somehow.

**Result**

I got it working with the config below. I had to extend `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` and simply `return "";` for both of its abstract methods.

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="http403ForbiddenEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthFilter" />
</security:http>
<bean id="preAuthFilter" class="com.hercules.ratinggame.business.security.IpAddressPreAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</bean>
<bean id="http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/>
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider
        ref="ipAddressAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you use `auto-config="true"` which means you get [few filters configured iunder the hood](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-auto-config), including `<form-login>` element with `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` filter.

Also, to *hit this authentication provider on every page visit* you'll need a filter which can obtain data from request (IP address as far as I can see). The filter will probably be [`RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.html) or more likely [your own `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` implementation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.html) which will have access to your autentication-manager.

To sum up, configuration will look like:

```
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:logout /> <!-- optional -->
    <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"
            ref="ipFromRequestPreAuthenticationFilter" />
</security:http>

<!-- this will probably extend AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter -->
<bean id="ipFromRequestPreAuthenticationFilter"
        class="com.example.IpFromRequestPreAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="ipAddressAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
```